# Genie framework does not install under Julia 1.2

Tags: julia

I try to install Genie framework with

```
(v1.2) pkg> add Genie
```

And it writes:

> ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
>    * Genieframework (not found in project, manifest or registry)
>   Please specify by known `name=uuid`.

How can I solve this? Other Julia packages do install without problem.

Comment: can you update this with what the `st` command returns?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the normal troubleshooting steps for packages: Try `build`, `free`, `resolve`, and maybe `gc`.

It installed without issue on my computer for Julia v1.1.1, v1.2, and v1.3.

```
              _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.2.0 (2019-08-20)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

(v1.2) pkg> add Genie
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/JuliaPOMDP`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/Registry`
 Resolving package versions...
 Installed Quadrature ──────── v1.0.0
 Installed DiffEqSensitivity ─ v4.4.0
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.2/Project.toml`
  [c43c736e] + Genie v0.22.8
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.2/Manifest.toml`
  [621f4979] ↑ AbstractFFTs v0.4.1 ⇒ v0.5.0
  [c7e460c6] + ArgParse v0.6.2
  [4fba245c] ↑ ArrayInterface v2.0.0 ⇒ v2.1.0
  [336ed68f] ↑ CSV v0.5.18 ⇒ v0.5.19
  [324d7699] ↑ CategoricalArrays v0.7.3 ⇒ v0.7.4
  [53a63b46] ↑ CodeTools v0.6.4 ⇒ v0.6.5
  [2b5f629d] ↑ DiffEqBase v6.7.0 ⇒ v6.9.1
  [01453d9d] ↑ DiffEqDiffTools v1.5.0 ⇒ v1.6.0
  [41bf760c] ↑ DiffEqSensitivity v4.3.0 ⇒ v4.4.0
  [31c24e10] ↑ Distributions v0.21.10 ⇒ v0.21.11
  [d4d017d3] ↑ ExponentialUtilities v1.5.1 ⇒ v1.6.0
  [c87230d0] ↑ FFMPEG v0.2.3 ⇒ v0.2.4
  [7a1cc6ca] ↑ FFTW v1.0.1 ⇒ v1.1.0
  [8fc22ac5] + FilePaths v0.8.0
  [48062228] ↓ FilePathsBase v0.7.0 ⇒ v0.6.2
  [c43c736e] + Genie v0.22.8
  [708ec375] + Gumbo v0.5.1
  [77172c1b] + HttpCommon v0.5.0
  [a09fc81d] ↑ ImageCore v0.8.5 ⇒ v0.8.6
  [6a3955dd] ↑ ImageFiltering v0.6.6 ⇒ v0.6.7
  [916415d5] ↑ Images v0.19.0 ⇒ v0.19.1
  [aa1ae85d] ↑ JuliaInterpreter v0.7.4 ⇒ v0.7.5
  [2ec943e9] ↑ Libz v1.0.0 ⇒ v1.0.1
  [e6f89c97] + LoggingExtras v0.4.0
  [442fdcdd] ↑ Measures v0.3.0 ⇒ v0.3.1
  [39ec1447] + Millboard v0.2.1
  [66fc600b] ↑ ModernGL v1.0.0 ⇒ v1.1.1
  [d9ec5142] ↑ NamedTupleTools v0.12.0 ⇒ v0.12.1
  [49dea1ee] + Nettle v0.4.0
  [4d1e1d77] + Nullables v1.0.0
  [6fe1bfb0] ↑ OffsetArrays v0.11.2 ⇒ v0.11.4
  [429524aa] ↑ Optim v0.19.5 ⇒ v0.19.7
  [1dea7af3] ↑ OrdinaryDiffEq v5.26.2 ⇒ v5.26.4
  [1fd47b50] ↑ QuadGK v2.1.1 ⇒ v2.3.1
  [67601950] ↑ Quadrature v0.1.1 ⇒ v1.0.0
  [79098fc4] ↑ Rmath v0.5.1 ⇒ v0.6.0
  [f2b01f46] ↑ Roots v0.8.3 ⇒ v0.8.4
  [47a9eef4] ↑ SparseDiffTools v1.0.0 ⇒ v1.1.0
  [4c63d2b9] ↑ StatsFuns v0.9.1 ⇒ v0.9.2
  [b718987f] + TextWrap v0.3.0
  [81def892] ↑ VersionParsing v1.1.3 ⇒ v1.2.0
```